# Custom React Native Plugin is null (iOS)

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a react native plugin. Android works like charm, but iOS makes some troubles. The plugin is always null.

**Files:**

myPlugin-bridging-header.h

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

myPlugin.m

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyPlugin, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(multiply:(float)a withB:(float)b
                withResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                withRejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end
```

myPlugin.swift

```swift
import Foundation

@objc(MyPlugin)
class MyPlugin: NSObject {

   @objc(multiply:withB:withResolver:withRejecter:)
   func multiply(a: Float, b: Float, resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
       resolve(a*b)
   }
}
```

index.js

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { MyPlugin } = NativeModules;

export default MyPlugin;
```

**Usage**

```js
import MyPlugin from 'my-plugin';

[...]

console.log(MyPlugin); // is null

MyPlugin.multiply(2, 8).then((value) => {
    console.log('value: ', value);
});
```

I don't know what is missing. The plugin is always null. Is `@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyPlugin, NSObject)` not enough to make the module available?

Answer (score 0):

Add missing function moduleName in your swift file

```
  override class func moduleName() -> String! {
    return "MyPlugin"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue. It's still null 